# Passed Json is not accepted by controller

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I get this result from creating JSON in my view

```
header:{"ScheduledVisit":"08/02/2017 12:00 AM","Company":"fdsa","ContactPerson":"asfd","Phone":"asdf","Purpose":"fasd","Detail":"asdf"}
```

My model looks like this:

```
public class ScheduleVisit
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Required")]
    public DateTime ScheduledVisit { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string ContactPerson { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Purpose { get; set; }
    public string Detail { get; set; }
}
```

I pass my data like so:

```
document.getElementById("btn_submit_schedule").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if ($("#scheduledVisit").val().length === 0) {
            $("#scheduledVisit").focus();
        }

        var obj = {};
        obj.ScheduledVisit = document.getElementById("scheduledVisit").value;
        obj.Company = document.getElementById("company").value;
        obj.ContactPerson = document.getElementById("contactPerson").value;
        obj.Phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
        obj.Purpose = document.getElementById("purpose").value;
        obj.Detail = document.getElementById("detail").value;
        console.log(obj);
        addSchedule(obj);
    });

    function addSchedule(data) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("ScheduleVisit", "ScheduleVisit")",
            data: {header: JSON.stringify(data)},
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}

and my controller looks like this:

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult ScheduleVisit(ScheduleVisit header)
    {

        return Json(false);
    }
```

When I run in debug mode and check if my controller accepts anything, I get null on the "header" parameter. Please show me where I am getting it wrong.

Comment: @Vanna I think its C# and ASP .NET

Comment: C# and javascript. The Json(false) is just to ouput something.

Comment: why is your class name and Action name are "ScheduleVisit"?

Comment: So it's easier to remember for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replaced `data: {header: JSON.stringify(data)}` with `data: data` with current solution.

This very complex and manual way you'll can use simple way as following

Assign name field to every element as same like id now

```
<input type="text" name="Company" value="" />
```

Use `serializeArray`

```
data: $("form").serializeArray(),
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you. No doubt, this is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that "data: {header: JSON.stringify(data)}" is not the same object as you expect on the controller.

This should work.

```
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "@Url.Action("ScheduleVisit", "ScheduleVisit")",
           data: data,
           ...
```

The controller expects an object like:

```
{
    "ScheduledVisit":"08/02/2017 12:00 AM",
    "Company":"fdsa",
    "ContactPerson":"asfd",
    "Phone":"asdf",
    "Purpose":"fasd",
    "Detail":"asdf"
}
```

Comment: I see... I'll do that as soon as I get in front of my PC. I hope your solution works!

Comment: Here's another question though, if I remove the header, how will I be able to pass two parameters. Actually I do have to pass 2 parameters. In the code I'm just saying one.

Comment: As much as I know you can't send multiple objects to an HttpPost. You can create an object containing both of your objects you want to send and using that.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35430045/post-multiple-objects-to-web-api