# How to pass Json data as parameter to web api using HttpClient

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I am using one asp.net application where i am calling web api using HttpClient.

in web API controller i am passing two parameter one is int and second is string.

Below is the code:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int submissionID, string jsonData)
{

}
```

This is working fine no issues when i am passing one int and one string parameter using httpClient

Below is my httpClient code:

```
public void GetWebApiData(int fileID, String jsonData)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var task = client.GetAsync("http://localhost:1469/api/Smartling/" + fileID + "/"+jsonData)
      .ContinueWith((taskwithresponse) =>
      {
          var response = taskwithresponse.Result;
          var jsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
          jsonString.Wait();
          var getVal = jsonString.Result;

      });
    task.Wait();
}
```

in the above code if i am passing instead of json data it's giving error response code 400 Bad Request.

same I used with jQuery ajax call and it's working fine no issues.

How to pass JSON data as parameter?

Comment: can you add a example on what jsonData looks like.

Comment: can you check my answer

Answer (score 4):

Say you have a class

```
public class Sample
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

On the client side

```
public async static Task<Boolean> GetWebApiData(int fileID,string jsonData)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    Sample model = new Sample();
    model = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Sample>(jsonData);
    var response = await client.GetAsync(string.Format("http://sample.com/api/test/{0}?model.value1={1}&model.value2={2}", fileID ,model.Value1, model.Value2));
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

On the server side

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id,[FromUri]Sample model)
{
    //do something
    return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Also please use "string" instead of "String" class in

public void GetWebApiData(int fileID, String jsonData)

if not working

Please try stringify or SerializeObject() to convert that data before you pass the data as argument.

something like
 JSON.stringify(jsonData);
or
 JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonData);

Comment: I used StringContent to deserialize my json data and able to call web api but now question is how to get json data back from StringContent?

Comment: JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
object obj = serializer.Deserialize<object>(jsDat);

Comment: jsDat is StringContent not string. Please provide code for StringContent to get value in string.

Comment: Give me one simple example pass json data to web api and return data back to json string format.

Comment: using this link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35344981/posting-to-a-web-api-using-httpclient-and-web-api-method-frombody-parameter-en" i used to convert json data to StringContent and it was able to pass this to web api and there i have to get back json string data back from StringContent parameter. Need help.